# Adjacent node swap in linked list but at output 1 node is missing

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, swap

This is the function i wrote for the node swap in a singly linked list.
There are other functions append, delete , length and etc.
now when the nodeswap is executed the left node gets missing.
for example.....
the linked list is
1->2->3
after the swap it becomes
1->3

```
void nodeswap()
{ 
    struct node *p,*q,*r;
    int i=1,loc,l;
    l=len();
    printf("At what position you want to swap nodes?\n");
    scanf("%d",&loc);
    if(loc>l)
    {
        printf("Swap not possible , no nodes beyond the location\n");
    }
    else
    {
        p=root;
        while(i<loc-1)
        {
            p=p->link;
            i++;
        }

        //access nodes
        q=p->link;
        r=q->link;
    }

        //swap
        //p,q,r
        //p,r,q
        q=r->link;
        r->link=q;
        p->link=r;


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in this line `q=r->link;`
You need to change this to `q->link = r->link`

For example if you have following four nodes in your linked list, with corresponding pointers

```
A->B->C->D
p  q  r
```

When you do  `q=r->link;`, this simply changes the setup to

```
A->B->C->D
p     r  q
```

Clearly this is not what you want, you want to set q's next node to be D, and to achieve that do `q->link = r->link`